# string concatenate multiple attribute values in xpath in c#

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

Is there is an xpath expression that can be used to concatenate multiple attribute values and that be used with XPathNavigator.Evaluate

```
    <root>
      <node class="string"></node>
      <node class="join"></node>
    </root>

    XPathNavigator.Evaluate(<expression>) 
    should return a string with value string;join
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should be OK:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(s);
var res = (document.Root.XPathEvaluate("/root/node/@class") as IEnumerable).Cast<XAttribute>().Aggregate("", (a, c) => a + ";" + c.Value);
res = res.Substring(1);
```

There is a better option in **XPath 2.0** with ***string-join*** but not sure it's implemented in .Net...

EDIT: otherwise building the XPath expression dynamically:

```
int count = (document.Root.XPathEvaluate("/root/node") as IEnumerable).Cast<XNode>().Count();
string xpath = "concat(";
for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
{
    xpath += "/root/node[" + i + "]/@class";

    if (i < count)
    {
        xpath += ", ';',";
    }
    else
    {
        xpath += ")";
    }
}
var res = document.Root.XPathEvaluate(xpath);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm dealing with an api that only accepts an expression for evaluation. Dont think string-join is implemented in .net

Comment: If you don't know in advance the number of nodes it will be hard. You could build the xpath expression on the fly depending on the number of node (see my edit)